# 404 error when refreshing the page - React App deployed on Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, deployment, frontend

I deployed a React App on heroku and every time that you refresh some page, a 404 error appears, 
like: `Cannot GET /create`

I have been searched about it and i found a related issue: 

[Question about 404 with React Router](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/issues/1)

So i created a static.json file redirect to the index.html but the error still happening.

```
{
    "root": "build/",
    "clean_urls": false,
    "routes": {
      "/**": "index.html"
    }
  }
```

Does anyone had the some problem with a react app deployed to heroku?

Comment: Are you using a Heroku buildpack? What are you serving the files with?

Comment: I'm not using heroku buildpack and i'm not using anything to serve the files

Comment: Is this a Create React App project? If so, try https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack which handles the 404 redirects for you.

Comment: Yes, it is. Okay, thanks for sharing, i'll try

Comment: Btw, thats the app - https://twobudget.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @cubrr after searching couple of hours and trying all the solutions provided, your solution fixed my problem!!! thank you so much :)

Comment: Great! You can add an answer with the steps you did so others can find help too :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a 2-year old question, but I was struggling with this not long ago and I think it might help anyone who runs into the same:

If you're receiving a 404 status code, it might be the case that the API doesn't have a `GET` endpoint set for that route. When you reload the page your browser is, essentially, making a `GET` request to the server, which sends back whatever it was set to - nothing, in this case, resulting in 404 error. On the other hand all that React actually does is re-render components, with no further `HTTP` requests, since it's only running on the client side. But not all server routes will have a `GET` endpoint set, and even if they do you'd end up having, let's say, a JSON - or something else - sent directly to your browser screen when you reload the page instead of the React app, so what you really want is to handle those requests correctly.

First it's very important to note that server routes and React routes **should not conflict** (a good idea is to prepend `/api` to your server routes). Rename your server routes and don't forget to also rename all API calls from React accordingly. Then, add the following code to your `server.js` file after defining your routes:

```
isProduction &&
  app.get("*", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build", "index.html"));
  });
```

This will take care of the `GET` requests executed by your browser on page refresh, making sure that Node always serves `index.html` (aka the React app) to supply those requests, so it can handle routing. Since your server routes are now renamed and will not conflict with the React ones, when you reload the page or try to navigate directly from the URL address bar you'll always get back the React app, which, in turn, will handle all API calls.